# How can I generate entities classes from database using Spring Boot and IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I trying to make a project using the Spring Initializr wizard and I already have a database, so I want to generate entities classes using Spring Boot and IntelliJ Idea.

Comment: Could you please write down steps you've taken so far? This question is way too general to answer. You need to setup your project in IDEA to support JPA/Hibernate and then you can use this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/generating-persistence-mappings.html

Comment: I created a project with Spring Initializr Wizard

Comment: Its only available in paid version. Community version users please dont waste time searching for it like I did!!!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Prerequisites are:

1. You have your Spring Boot project initialized correctly in IDEA
2. JPA persistence.xml file or similar has been generated correctly

Then you have to do these things:

1. [Create a DataSource](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/working-with-the-database-tool-window.html?origin=old_help#create_data_source) - here you will add a simple DataSource that will connect to your database. The setup should be intuitive - you only provide connection details and add DB drivers (IDEA can download them for you)
2. Add JPA/Hibernate facet. You can do it like [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/enabling-jpa-support.html?origin=old_help#d998879e350) or [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/enabling-hibernate-support.html?origin=old_help#d1785882e332).
3. Now you should be able to [generate entities using IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/generating-persistence-mappings.html). What you want to do here is choose `Generate by Database Schema`. The dialog will let you select the tables you want to use, the rest should be up to you.

Comment: This way generate only java classes. Is there any way to generate Kotlin data classes?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IntelliJ Idea's newer version (2022 or so) and not able to find the option in step 3 "`Generate by Database Schema`" in the accepted answer above then use the following:

Step 1: Create DataSource (as you create for database in Idea)
Step 2: Add JPA Hibernate Facet through File -> Project Structure ->Facets
Step 3: Generate Entities:  In the Database window,

1. Open the data connection to your DataSource,
2. Open schemas and find tables that you need to create entity classes for Right-click
3. Choose Tools -> Scripted Extensions -> Generate POJOs.groovy
4. Select the generation path (ideally your package for storing entities) and proceed.

These steps are verified and found working in `IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.3 (Ultimate Edition)`